# Uncommon question for everyone that is related to mathematics

Tags: soft-question

I'm still a student and something funny that I've seen is that many mathematicians evade the question, "What is mathematics?" And when they don't evade it, every person gives a different definition. So I was wondering, and I think this is the best place to ask: What is mathematics specifically?

I think it is a very curious question and I just want to see what you think.

Comment: *What are mathematics?* - What is art?

Comment: If it is true that everyone gives a different definition, how can you expect to get a specific definition?

Comment: The best answer to that question I know is: mathematics is what mathematicians do.

Comment: Why uncommon? Especially *for everyone that is related to mathematics*...

Comment: This question has nothing to do with mathematics.

Comment: See [Fields of mathematics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematics#Fields_of_mathematics), [Definitions of mathematics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definitions_of_mathematics), [Areas of mathematics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Areas_of_mathematics). Personally, I prefer Darwin's quote. :-)

Answer (score 1):

My very short answer: Mathematics is a very broad subject that seems to have grown out of questions of number and shape.  By now it has expanded to include questions of pattern, structure, and relationship.

Answer (score 0):

I think math could be defined as the study of axioms, and theorems you can derive from those axioms.

For example, arithmetic. The axioms are stuff like "zero exists" and "if $a=b$ and $b=c$ then $a=c$" and "every natural number has a number after it" and "$a+1$ means the number after $a$" and "$a+(b+c)=(a+b)+c$", etc.

And using the axioms, you can prove that $1+1=2$:
$a+1$ means the number after $a$.
Thus, $1+1$ means the number after $1$, which is $2$.

And, building off of that, you can prove that $2+2=4$:
$2+2=2+(1+1)$, by the previous theorem.
That equals $(2+1)+1$, since we can move parentheses around.
Since "$a+1$" means the number after $a$, we have:
$(2+1)+1=3+1=4$.

And geometry is what we get with Euclid's axioms. (Technically, there is non-Euclidean geometry, too...) etc.

Comment: I forgot to prove that $1$ exists. Proof: "$1$" is defined to be the number after $0$. Since $0$ exists, and every number has a number after it, $1$ exists. (Similarly for $2$, $3$, and $4$.)